# JavaScript undefined object even it shows data when checking by F12

Tags: javascript

Can any one help with this error.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var certifications = {
  nextCert : 0,
  data : [
   {
      "imgSrc" : "http://res.cloudinary.com/sharek/image/upload/v1460011761/UC-PJNHKQ02_r1gjmj.jpg"
   },
   {
  "imgSrc" : "http://res.cloudinary.com/sharek/image/upload/v1460011761/UC-KE5C95GA_aid30q.jpg"
   }
  ],
  getNextCert : function(){
    if(this.nextCert === this.data.length){
      this.nextCert = 0;
    }
    else{
      this.nextCert += 1;
    }
    return this.nextCert;
  },
  getCurrentCert : function() {
    return this.nextCert;
  },
  getImgCert : function() {
      return this.data[this.getNextCert()];
  }

};//certification object

var certContainer = $('#cert-container').html

var templateItem = $(certContainer);
templateItem.find('.img-responsive').attr('src',certifications.getImgCert()['imgSrc']);

 $('#nextBtn').click( function(){
    console.log(certifications.getImgCert()['imgSrc']);
    templateItem.find('.img-responsive').attr('src',certifications.getImgCert()['imgSrc']);

  });

});//document.ready
```

And here all of the home page I'm working on:

http://codepen.io/abomaged/pen/JXMXzV

Thanks a lot

Comment: Move the `var certifications` outside the document.ready

Comment: Hi mplungjan,I tried what you said it didn't help, I just forgot to say that the there is a data in the certifications variable, and the script is working even though it shows an error just in the console. thanks

Comment: Yeah, you also need to test this.nextCert AFTER incrementing as answered

Comment: Thanks mplungjan, that was the problem. I appreciate your help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your getNextCert function is returning an index that's outside the bounds of your certifications array. When nextCert is 1, the check to see if it's out of bounds of the array passes, so your code then increments nextCert to 2 and returns `data[2]` which is undefined. You need to change your getNextCert function:

```
  getNextCert : function(){
    this.nextCert += 1;
    if(this.nextCert === this.data.length){
      this.nextCert = 0;
    }
    return this.nextCert;
  },
```